# Get the names Instead IDs Numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ajax

I have a problem as i have created three cascading dropdownlist which shows the countries and the states and cities, but i would like save what dropdownlist shows, you can get more information if you click on the below link as i have record what is happening with me. Thanks for your support all.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAx3cvHqKf0&feature=youtu.be

**ASP.NET markup**

```
<div class="banner728">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/images/general/bann72890.png" />
</div>
<div class="space">
</div>
<div class="style6">
    <strong style="font-size: medium">Registre New User</strong></div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table style="width: 69%; height: 338px;" align="center">


   <tr>

   <td class="style5"> &nbsp; Användarnamn</td>
    <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="UsrNme" runat="server" Width="258px" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
   <td>
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Userreqlbl" runat="server" 
           ControlToValidate="UsrNme" ErrorMessage="This field is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
       <br />
       </td>


   </tr>


    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Förnamn
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="fnbox" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="258px" 
                ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Efternamn
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="lnamebox" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="258px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Lösenord
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="passtxtbx1" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="258px" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="passtxtbx1"
                ErrorMessage="This part is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Återskrivnings Lösenord
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="passtxtbx2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="258px" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="passtxtbx1"
                ControlToValidate="passtxtbx2" ErrorMessage="The password is not match" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; E-post
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="emailbox" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="258px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="emailbox"
                ErrorMessage="Invalid Format" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Land
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="countrdrdolst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="countrdrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Län
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="statedrdolst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="statedrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Stad
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style11">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="citiesdrdolst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="citiesdrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style12">
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Postnummer
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="postbox" runat="server" Width="258px"  
                Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Personlig bild
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>


   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp;
            </td>
        <td class="style8">







            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" onclick="btnSave_Click" Text="Create" CausesValidation="True"/>







        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C# code**

```
   public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    string sc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable countrycascd = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adaptar = new SqlDataAdapter("select [countryID],[country] FROM [countr]", con);
                adaptar.Fill(countrycascd);

                countrdrdolst.DataSource = countrycascd;
                countrdrdolst.DataTextField = "country";
                countrdrdolst.DataValueField = "countryID";
                countrdrdolst.DataBind();
            }

            countrdrdolst.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select country", "0"));
        }
    }





    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string sqlstatment = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (UID, FN, LN, Password, RePass, Email,CountID, State,City, Post, Img) VALUES (@UID,@FN,@LN,@Password,@RePass,@Email,@CountID,@State,@City,@Post,@Img)";

        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlstatment;

        //Insert the parameters first
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", fnbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", lnamebox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passtxtbx1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RePass", passtxtbx2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountID", countrdrdolst.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", statedrdolst.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citiesdrdolst.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post", postbox.Text);

        //Check if there's a file or not
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/users/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", FileUpload1.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            //Must add the paramater value to any value or DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", "");
        }




        //Open the connection and execute the command
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Close the connection
        cn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");


        }

    protected void countrdrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int countryID = Convert.ToInt32(countrdrdolst.SelectedValue);
        DataTable StateDT = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adaptar = new SqlDataAdapter("Select [StateID],[State] FROM [State] WHERE [countryID] = " + countryID, con2);

            adaptar.Fill(StateDT);

            statedrdolst.DataSource = StateDT;
            statedrdolst.DataTextField = "State";
            statedrdolst.DataValueField = "StateID";
            statedrdolst.DataBind();
        }

        statedrdolst.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select State", "0"));


    }

    protected void statedrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int StateID = Convert.ToInt32(statedrdolst.SelectedValue);
        DataTable Citydt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adaptar = new SqlDataAdapter("select [CityID],[City] FROM [Cities] WHERE [StateID] = " + StateID, con3);
            adaptar.Fill(Citydt);

            citiesdrdolst.DataSource = Citydt;
            citiesdrdolst.DataTextField = "City";
            citiesdrdolst.DataValueField = "CityID";
            citiesdrdolst.DataBind();
        }

        citiesdrdolst.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select City", "0"));
    }

    protected void citiesdrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dropdownlist.Text gets the SelectedValue property of the dropdownlist control.

I think dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Text should give you the name of the country but I can't check it at the minute.

However it's probably better to store the ID rather than the name in your userinfo table. What if the name of a state changes for example or a city can be spelt in more than one way?

Comment: Thanksssssssssss for you so much its work as u mention i have to add .SelectedItem.Text thank you again :-))))